# Cannot load UIMA PEAR package through the package installer GUI

Tags: java, maven, uima, uima-pear

I have a problem related to installing a UIMA PEAR package containing an Annotator component. I am using PearPackageMavenPlugin for the job with the following setup:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
                    <artifactId>PearPackagingMavenPlugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- PEAR file component classpath settings -->
                                <classpath>$main_root/bin</classpath>
                                <!-- PEAR file main component descriptor -->
                                <mainComponentDesc>desc/S4DocumentUimaAnnotator.xml</mainComponentDesc>
                                <!-- PEAR file component ID -->
                                <componentId>S4DocumentAnnotator</componentId>
                                <!-- PEAR file UIMA datapath settings -->
                                <datapath>$main_root/resources</datapath>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>package</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

`

I have constructed a special maven profile building the project in a bin directory instead of target so all my compiled classes are there that is why I have pointed the classpath setting of the plugin at $main_root/bin.

Finally when I load the built pear package I get the following error:

`Verification of S4DocumentAnnotator failed => 
 org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: The class com.ontotext.s4.api.components.uima.S4DocumentUimaAnnotator is not a valid Analysis Component.  You must specify an Annotator, CAS Consumer, Collection Reader, or CAS Multiplier. If you are calling ResourceManager.setExtensionClassPath, this error can also be caused if you have put UIMA framework jar files on the extension classpath, which is not allowed. (Descriptor: file:/home/ceco/s4_stuff/my_pear/S4DocumentAnnotator/desc/S4DocumentUimaAnnotator.xml)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:228)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:170)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448)
    at org.apache.uima.pear.tools.InstallationTester.testAnalysisEngine(InstallationTester.java:218)
    at org.apache.uima.pear.tools.InstallationTester.doTest(InstallationTester.java:113)
    at org.apache.uima.pear.tools.InstallationController.verifyComponentInstallation(InstallationController.java:1110)
    at org.apache.uima.pear.tools.InstallationController.verifyComponent(InstallationController.java:1993)
    at org.apache.uima.tools.pear.install.InstallPear.installPear(InstallPear.java:389)
    at org.apache.uima.tools.pear.install.InstallPear.access$000(InstallPear.java:80)
    at org.apache.uima.tools.pear.install.InstallPear$RunInstallation.run(InstallPear.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`

I do not understand why the UIMA jars are not supposed to be packaged when the idea of the PEAR package is to be self-contained and not depend on the system it is ran on?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would try:

> The class com.ontotext.s4.api.components.uima.S4DocumentUimaAnnotator is not a valid Analysis Component

Check that S4DocumentUimaAnnotator is valid. Unzip the PEAR and check the xml.

> If you are calling ResourceManager.setExtensionClassPath, this error can also be caused if you have put UIMA framework jar files on the extension classpath, which is not allowed.

Did you try to print the extension classpath?

Else you could try to use a plain java version of the PEAR, meaning: manually unzip it and create a normal java project with it.

Answer (score 1):

One common issue I ran into several times and which creates exactly this error message is that my PEAR contains uimaj-common.jar in the lib folder. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old but what I think you should do is set the scope of the uima dependencies to `provided`. The PEAR needs only it's dependencies to run, the enviroment it'll be used should have the uima dependencies set to use all the uima features and pears

Provided dependencies won't be copied to the lib folder of the PEAR

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be going on, but going by your error message, the first thing I would determine is whether or not the `uimaj-core` jar file is being excluded from the build of the PEAR file. It should be. (Take a look at the error message above.) I just ran into this problem myself, and I got around it by adding this to my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <!-- Copy the dependencies to the lib folder for the PEAR to copy. -->
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <!-- An exception happens when using a PEAR if the archive includes this jar. -->
                <excludeArtifactIds>uimaj-core</excludeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I recently posted a parent POM file and a project-specific POM file to my Gist. You're welcome to take a look at what I'm doing. (One of the things I'm doing is copying over my `desc` directory, which contains my AE's descriptor XML file, to the root of my project directory, so that the maven-pear plugin can copy it into the PEAR archive properly.)

Parent POM:

https://gist.github.com/software-mariodiana/d46e10fca53dc6e6c0f16e20563476b8

Project-specific POM:

https://gist.github.com/software-mariodiana/e9a0f0f03a49d33dcc32655170fd4841

Good luck!